# how to get a tag value in href with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

There's a piece of html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Code</title>
<body>
<div id="suggestions">
content
<p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=kljljl">link</a></p>
<p><a href="/pd?email=6@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsfsa">link</a></p>
</div>
<div id="list">
    kklj
    <p><a href="/pd?email=10@email.com&pd=187&name=4fdaf">link1</a></p>
    dll
    <p><a href="/pd?email=2@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsf">link2</a></p>
    fdf
    <p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=hgfhd">link3</a></p>
    fdsaf
    <p><a href="/pd?email=4@email.com&pd=187&name=ertewt">link4</a></p>
    fdsaf
    <p><a href="/pd?email=5@email.com&pd=187&name=gfdsg">link7</a></p>
    fdasf
    <p><a href="/pd?email=8@email.com&pd=187&name=fdsgfgsg">link3</a></p>
    fdsaf
    <p><a href="/pd?email=dd@email.com&pd=187&name=cxvbvcb">link8</a></p>
    fdsafd
    <p><a href="/pd?email=jh@email.com&pd=187&name=ujjhgh">link3</a></p>
</div>
<script>
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  
})
</script>
</html>
```

I want to be able to get the `email` value and `pd` value of the current `href` when I click on a `href` under `list`. I can get it easily with JQuery, but I don't know how to do without it. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this way

```js
const List_els = document.querySelector('#list')

List_els.addEventListener('click', function(e)
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('a')) return // verify where the click is done
  
  e.preventDefault()  // disable the href page loading
  
    let url = new URL(e.target.href)
  
  console.clear()
  console.log( url.searchParams.get('email'))
  setTimeout(console.clear,3000)
  })
```

```css
p { margin: .1em 0 0 2em ; }
```

```html
<div id="suggestions">
  content
  <p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=kljljl">link</a></p>
  <p><a href="/pd?email=6@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsfsa">link</a></p>
</div>
<div id="list">
  kklj
  <p><a href="/pd?email=10@email.com&pd=187&name=4fdaf">link1</a></p>
  dll
  <p><a href="/pd?email=2@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsf">link2</a></p>
  fdf
  <p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=hgfhd">link3</a></p>
  fdsaf
  <p><a href="/pd?email=4@email.com&pd=187&name=ertewt">link4</a></p>
  fdsaf
  <p><a href="/pd?email=5@email.com&pd=187&name=gfdsg">link7</a></p>
  fdasf
  <p><a href="/pd?email=8@email.com&pd=187&name=fdsgfgsg">link3</a></p>
  fdsaf
  <p><a href="/pd?email=dd@email.com&pd=187&name=cxvbvcb">link8</a></p>
  fdsafd
  <p><a href="/pd?email=jh@email.com&pd=187&name=ujjhgh">link3</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but I need to get the href value in  div `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've written a function looks like jQuery but it's pure Vanilla JavaScript.
It's the standard way to get value from any URL. Here you justt have to call this function to get search data. You can apply multiple events here like click, mouseenter etc

```
 QueryURL('a').on( 'click', response => {
    console.log(response)
} )
```

Attachment / Main code is here

```js
window.onload = function () {

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * Get url query value
     * @param selector refers to anchor link
     * 
     */ 

    const QueryURL = selector => {
        const methods = {
            element : document.querySelectorAll( selector ), 
            on: function( eventName, callback ) {
                this.element.forEach( btn => {
                    btn.addEventListener( eventName, ev => {
                        ev.preventDefault();
                        ev.stopPropagation();
                        if( ev.target.href ) {
                            const url = new URL(ev.target.href);
                            const searchParams = new URLSearchParams( url.search );
                            callback( Object.fromEntries(searchParams) )
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                } )
            }
        }

        return methods;
    } 

    /*
    * ========================================
    * Init / Call the function
    * ========================================
    */ 
    
    QueryURL('a').on( 'click', response => {
        console.log(response)
    } )
    
    
}
```

```html
<div id="suggestions">
    content
    <p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=kljljl">link</a></p>
    <p><a href="/pd?email=6@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsfsa">link</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        kklj
        <p><a href="/pd?email=10@email.com&pd=187&name=4fdaf">link1</a></p>
        dll
        <p><a href="/pd?email=2@email.com&pd=187&name=afdsf">link2</a></p>
        fdf
        <p><a href="/pd?email=1@email.com&pd=187&name=hgfhd">link3</a></p>
        fdsaf
        <p><a href="/pd?email=4@email.com&pd=187&name=ertewt">link4</a></p>
        fdsaf
        <p><a href="/pd?email=5@email.com&pd=187&name=gfdsg">link7</a></p>
        fdasf
        <p><a href="/pd?email=8@email.com&pd=187&name=fdsgfgsg">link3</a></p>
        fdsaf
        <p><a href="/pd?email=dd@email.com&pd=187&name=cxvbvcb">link8</a></p>
        fdsafd
        <p><a href="/pd?email=jh@email.com&pd=187&name=ujjhgh">link3</a></p>
    </div>
```